# Match Multiple Occurrence of String - Elixir Regex

Tags: elixir

I've got this

`^A[A-Z0-9]*$`

This Matches strings that Begins with 'A' and can contain Numbers and Upper cases only, but does not match is the string occurrence is within a sentence.

However, I would love to get all the occurrences of a particular Pattern within a String. The String would always have 14 alpahanumeric characters and would always be in Uppercases and begin with the alphabet 'A'.

As an example,

`This is a String that matches A1LN2K8771FZ7B does this A283GSDJESLEKS with a randon ADSKEISKIDDSER`

I want match and extact all the 3 UPPERCASES that start with A in that sample string

I've tried variances that does not seem to do what I intend.

Please I'm also open to possible alternatives other than Using regex in solving this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to remove the `^` and `$` so that it matches anywhere in a line. You can then use `Regex.scan` to get all the matches:

```
iex(1)> s = "This is a String that matches A1LN2K8771FZ7B does this A283GSDJESLEKS with a randon ADSKEISKIDDSER"
"This is a String that matches A1LN2K8771FZ7B does this A283GSDJESLEKS with a randon ADSKEISKIDDSER"
iex(2)> Regex.scan(~r/A[A-Z0-9]*/, s)
[["A1LN2K8771FZ7B"], ["A283GSDJESLEKS"], ["ADSKEISKIDDSER"]]
```

To get a flat list of matches, you can map over `hd/1`:

```
iex(3)> Regex.scan(~r/A[A-Z0-9]*/, s) |> Enum.map(&hd/1)
["A1LN2K8771FZ7B", "A283GSDJESLEKS", "ADSKEISKIDDSER"]
```

---

If you want to only match `A` followed by 13 `[A-Z0-9]`, you can use the regex `~r/A[A-Z0-9]{13}/` instead.

Comment: ,Thank You so Much. Please how can i restrict it to match only those with 14 characters,discarding the rest?

Comment: Maybe it would be a good idea to replace `^` and `$` with word boundary `\b`. This will ensure that partial matches within a longer sequence are not matched.

Comment: @Dogbert, Thank You so much!